# divs with vertical line

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need help about this image. How can I  set it up in css and in html thank you in advance if anyone will give time to help me.[image]

Comment: You have two options: a) start coding. b) pay someone to code it for you. You can't ask for free work on [so]. Come here when there's something you don't understand or something doesn't work the way you expect it to. And, before you ask, make sure it hasn't been asked before. I think you clearly understand why the above layout is not currently displayed the way you want it. Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I've been coding for several months but there is something I don't understand and how it goes. So that's why I'm asking and seek help.

Comment: You probably want to read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would recommend is to consider the image to be a **[`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)** of one element. Then create a child of that element that only occupies the left-hand half of the image. In order to achieve this, the child needs the following styles:

```
#child {
  position: relative; /* To position the border in relation to the image parent */
  width: calc(50% - 2px); /* 2px correlates to the width of the border */
  height: 100%; /* To occupy the full height of the image */
}
```

Now the the element is invisibly sitting on the left-hand half of the image, you can apply a border to the right-hand side of this element with `border-right: 2px solid cyan`.

This results in a line halfway through the image, as can be seen in the following:

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/100);
}

#child {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 2px solid cyan;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Obisidians](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47298296/4665) answer is good....I'm going to tweak it slightly be removing an HTML element and using `:before`, keeping the background image, but treating the line a little differently

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(http:/fillmurray.com/300/200);
  position:relative;
}

#container::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 1px);
  width:2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:cyan;
  content: '';
}

#container > div
{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>Some Content</div>
</div>
```

This way you have more freedom of the child contents